# Running Code After Infinite While Loop

Tags: c#, while-loop, infinite-loop

I'm trying to make a console application. I want the ". . ." after "Press any key to exit" to blink.
The blinking is working fine and all, but now my Console.ReadKey() is unreachable code.
I'm just wondering if there is anyway to let the Console.ReadKey() line be reached, or where I would move it to be able to let it be run?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string blinkExit = ". . .";           //Variable for blinking periods after 'exit'

        Console.Write("\n\nPress any key to exit");              //Displays a message to press any key to exit in the console

        while (true)
        {
            WriteBlinkingText(blinkExit, 500, true);
            WriteBlinkingText(blinkExit, 500, false);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

private static void WriteBlinkingText(string text, int delay, bool visible)
    {
        if (visible)
            Console.Write(text);
        else
            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
                Console.Write(" ");
            Console.CursorLeft -= text.Length;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
    }
```

Comment: If you need to do two things at the same time, try threads. Alternatively you could check keyboard state in the loop...

Comment: I should have added, I'm quite new to C#; It's my first semester in it actually. I'll look into keyboard states, but what would you recommend as the most simple solution?

Comment: Ah, this is homework?

Comment: Yes. We don't NEED to do a loop, I'm just adding it for extra. Our assignment literally is just declare, and set variables then display them. I want to do something extra.

Comment: In general, I just don't recommend doing UI like things in a command window, unless this is an assignment ;)

Comment: I would not give you extra credit for doing this.

Comment: I didn't say anything about getting extra credit. I just said I wanted to do something extra. I just like to add extra things to my program to make it stand out. I realize I won't get extra credit, but it will still make me stand out, which is arguably better then extra credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you just want this text to blink until a key is pressed by the user.  If that is the case then why not just loop until there is a key available to be read?

```
while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
{
    WriteBlinkingText(blinkExit, 500, true);
    WriteBlinkingText(blinkExit, 500, false);
}
```

This avoids all of the nasty issues that can come up with using multiple threads

Comment: While it has a bit of lag before it actually exits the program, this works wonderfully! I was looking at the KeyAvailable function, and apparently it's what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

just change your while code with this

```
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                WriteBlinkingText(blinkExit, 500, true);
                WriteBlinkingText(blinkExit, 500, false);
            }
        });
```

pressing any key will close the console

Comment: This works, thank you. If it's not too much, may I ask exactly what that first line is doing to make this work?

Comment: Its starts a new task, which is a managed thread to run a new Action which has the syntax of `() => { /* code */ }`

Comment: Again, I'm new. So anything inside the task is run separately from the main code running? As in, the code runs up to the whole loop, then runs the loop inside it's own "thread", but will also continue and run the Console.ReadKey()?

Comment: @WolfieeifloW, i would suggest you do go read on MSDN how task work. but mostly yes you are right

Comment: I've already used the MSDN a bit, but I will definitely be looking at it a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine threads as workers, when you use the console application, you are working on one thread, and by using a loop which doesn't end, you are essentially stopping any other task from occurring from that point onwards because the thread is busy looping!

To solve the problem you need to place a trigger of sorts in the loop which is going to exit once a key is pressed. I've demonstrated a simple way to do this below.

Examine the code, you'll find that I've used a new class called `Interlocked`, the reason I used this is to avoid any thread safety issues, thread safety is a deep topic, and isn't something I want to be trying to explain in a few sentences, but the idea is that any resources being shared between two different threads, must be locked. You'll also find a lambda expression, these are all intermediate topics, and trying to learn them now is going to achieve one thing... a headache!

```
    private static long _isKeyPressed;

    private static void Main()
    {
        // Create a new Thread and Start it. 
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            // Variable for blinking periods after 'exit'
            const string blinkExit = ". . .";

            // Displays a message to press any key to exit in the console
            Console.Write("\n\nPress any key to exit"); 

            // Run until no keys are pressed.
            while (Interlocked.Read(ref _isKeyPressed) == 0)
            {
                WriteBlinkingText(blinkExit, 500, true);
                WriteBlinkingText(blinkExit, 500, false);
            }
        }).Start();

        Console.ReadKey();

        // Once a key has been pressed, increment the value of _isKeyPressed to 1.
        // This will indicate to the thread running above that it should exit it's loop.
        // as _isKeyPressed is no longer equal to 0.
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _isKeyPressed);
    }

    private static void WriteBlinkingText(string text, int delay, bool visible)
    {
        if (visible) Console.Write(text);
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
        }

        Console.CursorLeft -= text.Length;
        Thread.Sleep(delay);
    }
```

Comment: The problem with this, is the thread will not terminate, and thus the application won't terminate

Comment: I am pretty sure doing this will cause the program to hang after a key is pressed. The right way to use TPL for this would be with a cancellationToken; inside the while loop, first line checks if token is passed, and exits loop.